Cannot post message with Instagram Api
I am trying to respond to a user comment on an Instagram post for a Professional account following the Instagram API with Instagram Login docs and keep getting this error:
{"error":{"message":"Invalid OAuth access token - Cannot parse access token","type":"OAuthException","code":190,"fbtrace_id":"Alx1XMAKjBlUgf7Rz61Hm2i"}}

YES, my token is valid (checked on token debugger) PLUS I am able to use the token for other functions such as fetching media and adding a comment to a post just fine.
According to the docs:
const result = await fetch(
    `https://graph.facebook.com/v21.0/${ig_pro_account_id}/messages`,
    {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            Authorization: `Bearer ${access_token}`,
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ 
            recipient: {
                id: <scoped-user-id>,
            },
            message: {
                text: 'Here is a reply',
            },
        })
    }
)
.then(res => res.json())
.catch((err: any) => console.log(`Error sending message: ${err.message}`));

I have tried appending the access_token to the URL and even putting it in the body, but always the same response.  The docs say to use it as a Bearer token, though.
App has not gone through review yet as according to the submission criteria I have to show all of this working in my submission, but am using the test accounts setup in the App and everything but this one function is working.  I'm even getting webhooks when comments are left on posts. Any help appreciated!

Well...derp....I just realized that I was calling the facebook endpoint and not the instagram endpoint...so...solved! :D

is there a difference? pretty sure its as you have it up there for instagram too  https://graph.facebook.com/v21.0/${ig_pro_account_id}
